# Как сделать отступ второй строки li от его верхнего элемента, а не ряда?

Tags: html, css

Не могу понять как сделать отступ у элементов `li` от их верхних пунктов, а не от всего ряда.

[image: меню]

```css
.megamenu__columns.megamenu__columns-image-off {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}

.megamenu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.megamenu__columns {
  padding-top: 25px !important;
  padding-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.megamenu__columns .level-menu {
  width: 24%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.megamenu__columns .level-menu li {
  list-style: none;
}

.megamenu__columns .level-menu li.title {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<ul class="megamenu__columns megamenu__columns-image-off">
  <li class="level-menu level1">
    <ul>
      <li class="title"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level-menu level1">
    <ul>
      <li class="title"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level-menu level1">
    <ul>
      <li class="title"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level-menu level1">
    <ul>
      <li class="title"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level-menu level1">
    <ul>
      <li class="title"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level-menu level1">
    <ul>
      <li class="title"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level-menu level1">
    <ul>
      <li class="title"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level-menu level1">
    <ul>
      <li class="title"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level-menu level1">
    <ul>
      <li class="title"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level-menu level1">
    <ul>
      <li class="title"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level-menu level1">
    <ul>
      <li class="title"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level-menu level1">
    <ul>
      <li class="title"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
      <li class="level2"><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите получить в результате.

Comment: Мне понятно что именно не получается, так как можно же задать `margin-top` или `margin-bottom` для соответствующих элементов.

Comment: Отрицательный margin-top пробовал, становится как нужно. Но тут проблема, что это меню на сайте будет часто меняться, и каждый раз лезть править css не хочется.

Answer (score 0):

Если допустимо расположить пункты меню по порядку не слева направо, а сверху вниз с переносом, можно сделать многоколоночную верстку:

```
.megamenu__columns {
    column-count:4;
}

.megamenu__columns .level-menu {
    width: auto;
    display: block;
}

.megamenu__columns .level-menu ul {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    white-space: nowrap; 
}
.megamenu__columns .level-menu li a {white-space: normal;}
```